# В html письме, отправленном через PHPMailer, приходит закодированный текст. Как раскодировать?

Tags: php, sendmail, phpmailer

На локальном сервере отправляю html письмо с помощь phpmailer, письмо приходит с закодированным текстом. Выглядит он примерно так:

> =D0=9D=D0=B0=D0=B8=D0=BC=D0=B5=D0=
> =BD=D0=BE=D0=B2=D0=B0=D0=BD=D0=B8=D0=B5:

```
$mail = new PHPMailer(true);

    try {
        $mail->CharSet = "UTF-8";
        $mail->setFrom('admin@potok.ru', 'potok.ru');
        $mail->addAddress($user_email);

        $mail->isHTML(true);
        $mail->Subject = "Новый заказ №{$order_id}";
        ob_start();
        require \APP . "/views/mail/{$tpl}.php";
        $body = ob_get_clean();
        $mail->Body = $body;
        return $mail->send();
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        return false;
    }
```

Вот заголовок:

```
To: kozlovv.ds@ya.ru
Subject: =?iso-8859-1?B?0J3QvtCy0YvQuSDQt9Cw0LrQsNC3IOKEljk=?=
X-PHP-Originating-Script: 0:PHPMailer.php
Date: Wed, 2 Nov 2022 16:07:40 +0300
From: "potok.ru" <admin@potok.ru>
Message-ID: <8YFQ9vsIloPgZPOb0IN6oWVeCxbR5ZPEDpLxfHNsbA@shop.local>
X-Mailer: PHPMailer 6.6.5 (https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer)
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable
```

Я так понимаю кодирует последняя строчка? Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

Comment: Текст письма с логов брали?

Comment: OpenServer\userdata\temp\email с этой папки

Comment: `Content-Transfer-Encoding` там есть такое?

Comment: Да, я сверху добавил заголовок, можете посмотреть.

Comment: Вот, `quoted-printable` это стандартная кодировка для мейлов, так что всё нормально должно быть с письмами. Тот случай, когда надо смотреть итоговый результат (входящие на почтовом ящике), а не логи

Comment: Ясно, спасибо! Тогда буду смотреть когда залью на хостинг.

Comment: попробуйте: `utf8_encode(quoted_printable_decode("=D0=9D=D0=B0=D0=B8=D0=BC=D0=B5=D0= =BD=D0=BE=D0=B2=D0=B0=D0=BD=D0=B8=D0=B5:"));`